# Set header when creating table from CSV

Tags: kdb

I have a csv "pf.csv":

```
Jules,Winnfield  
Vincent,Vega  
Mia,Wallace  
Marsellus,Wallace
```

And would like to specify a list of symbols which become the header when I read the csv. Normally I would load the csv like so:

```
("SS";enlist ",") 0: `$"pf.csv"
```

but that actually sets the first row as the keys in the flipped dictionary (i.e. the header in the table)
In the [documentation](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/ZeroColon) for `0:` I read

> Optionally, 0: can take a three-item list as its second argument,
>   containing the file handle, an offset at which to begin reading, and a
>   length to read.

But that's inconvenient as the offset has to be given in number of characters and not in lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go about this is to specify the column names before the bit you use to load the csv.

```
flip`fname`surname!("SS";",")0:`:pf.csv
```

You will also have to drop `enlist` because you do not have any column headers in your csv.

Another option would be to name the columns inside your *.csv file and then you can simply use enlist in your query to specify that the first row contains the column names.

Some more details here:

http://code.kx.com/q4m3/11_IO/#1152-variable-length-records
https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/ZeroColon#Load_Delimited_Records_.28Read_CSV.29

Answer (score 1):

Could you try

```
flip `firstName`lastName!("SS";",") 0: `$"pf.csv"
```